# Cannot initialize ng-model in JS rather than HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, initialization

HTML:

```
...
<input ng-init="item.check=false" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check">
...
<input ng-init="item.name=''" class="form-control" ng-model="item.name">
...
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
var refresh = function() {
    $scope.item.check = false;
    $scope.item.name = "";

}
//Call upon loading app to initialize values, also called upon events to refresh the field
refresh();
```

I initially thought that just the JS is sufficient to initialize the values and so I got rid of both the checkbox and the form's ng-init then ended up getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

The app works if I just leave both ng-init. It also works when I remove the ng-init from only one of the 2 elements (so either from the checkbox or the form) but it will not work if I remove both. What is going on here? Am I doing this correctly or is there a better way to initialize?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$scope.item = {}` in first line of your controller.

Javascript reports error when you are trying to access `$scope.item.name` when `$scope.item` itself doesn't exist (or not an object in some cases).

When you do `ng-init`, angular creates the object for you so you don't get the error.

Comment: I see! Is it correct to say that we are initializing item as an object or a dictionary?

Comment: Object. javascript doesn't have a dictionary type AFAIK, we just use object to implement one.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the controller

```
$scope.item = {};
```